# How to fix 'TypeError: Object arrays are not currently supported' error in numpy python 3 (matrix multiplication)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, neural-network, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to make my own neural network "library" (if you can call it that) for myself to use, since I am hobby-learning about them.

I wrote this code that makes a propagatable neural network by feeding it a structure of the desired network, and it worked pretty well.

**But** then when I tried giving the model a different amount of nodes, the code ***BUGGED***

I've already tried to edit the amount of nodes in each layer and see where that takes me, and I've found out that I only get this error when the first and the second layer have the same amount of nodes in them, but the output layer has a different amount. I've also tried to do the matrix multiplication of the structure that outputs the bug on paper, and it gave me an actual result (which I've double-checked for legitness a lot of times). So now I know that it has something to do with the practical and not theoretical.
There's clearly something wrong with the matrix multiplication, I think.

## The script's functions

> I had to include these functions in the question, so you can have a better inside on how this code works.

### is_iterable()

This function returns a boolean value that describes if the input is iterable

```
    def is_iterable(x):
        try:
            x[0]
            return True
        except:
            return False
```

### blueprint()

This function returns a copy of the input array but changes the elements that aren't iterable to 0's

```
    def blueprint(x):
        return [blueprint(e) if is_iterable(e) else 0 for e in x]
```

### build()

This function takes a model of your desired neural network structure as input, and outputs suited randomized biases and weights seperated in two different arrays
The 'randomize()' function returns a copy of the input array but changes the elements that aren't iterable to random floats between -1's and 1's.
The 'build-weights()' function returns randomized weights based on a model of a neural network.

```
    def build(x):

        def randomize(x):
            return np.array([randomize(n) if type(n) is list else random.uniform(-1, 1) for n in x])

        def build_weighs(x):
            y = []
            for i, l in enumerate(x):
                if i == len(x) - 1:
                    break
                y.append([randomize(x[i + 1]) for n in l])
            return np.array(y)

        return (randomize(x), build_weighs(x))
```

### apply_funcs()

This function applies a list of functions to another list of functions and then returns them. If the function list contains a 0, an element from the other list positioned in the same place will not be applied to any function.

```
    def apply_funcs(x, f):
        y = x
        i = 0
        for xj, fj in zip(x, f):
            if fj == 0:
                y[i] = xj
            else:
                y[i] = fj(xj)
            i += 1
        return y
```

### nn()

This is the class for making a neural network.
You can see that it has a function named, 'prop' for the forward propagation of the network.

```
    class nn:
        def __init__(self, structure, a_funcs=None):
            self.structure = structure
            self.b = np.array(structure[0])
            self.w = np.array(structure[1])
            if a_funcs == None:
                a_funcs = blueprint(self.b)
            self.a_funcs = np.array(a_funcs).

        def prop(self, x):
            y = np.array(x)
            if y.shape != self.b[0].shape:
                raise ValueError("The input needs to be intact with the Input Nodes\nInput: {} != Input Nodes: {}".format(blueprint(y), blueprint(self.b[0])))
            wi = 0
            # A loop through the layers of the neural network
            for i in range(len(self.b)):
                # This if statement is here so that the weights get applied in the right order
                if i != 0:
                    y = np.matmul(y, self.w[wi])
                    wi += 1
                # Applying the biases of layer i to the current information
                y = np.add(y, self.b[i])
                # Applying the activation functions to the current information
                y = apply_funcs(y, self.a_funcs[i])

            return y
```

## Defining a neural network structure and propagating it

**n** is containing the structure which is a 3 layer network containing respectively *2 nodes, 2 nodes and 3 nodes.*

```
    n = [[0] * 2, [0] * 2, [0] * 3]
    bot = nn(build(n))
    print(bot.prop([1] * 2))
```

When I do this I expect the code to output an array of three semi-random numbers like this:

```
    [-0.55889818  0.62762604  0.59222784]
```

but instead I get an error from numpy saying this:

```
    File "C:\Users\Black\git\Changbot\oper.py.py", line 78, in prop
        y = np.matmul(y, self.w[wi])
    TypeError: Object arrays are not currently supported
```

And the weirdest thing about this is that (as I said earlier) I only get this error when the first and the second layer have the same amount of nodes in them, but the output layer has a different amount. All the other times I get the expected output...

I have now again checked the values that are causing this error and I don't see any objects other than a list. It's the same when it's not bugging...
So I added this try-except statement:

```
    try:
        y = np.matmul(np.array(y), self.w[wi])
    except TypeError:
        print("y:{}\nself.w[wi]:{}".format(y, self.w[wi]))
```

It then outputs this:

```
    y:[1.6888437]
    self.w[wi]:[array([-0.19013173])]
```

Which should have the ability to be multiplied with each other
I have even tried copy pasting the values into an interpreter and multiplying them there, and it works there...

> NOTE: THIS IS A VERY BAD TEST AS THE COPY PASTE ARRAYS DOESN'T HAVE THE SAME DTYPES AS THE ACTUAL ARRAYS

```
    np.matmul([1.6888437], [np.array([-0.19013173])])
```

Output for the above:

```
    [-0.32110277]
```

## After looking at the answers

Okay. I have now found out that the object dtype arrays lies in the structure of the neural network by doing this at the end of the script:

```
    print("STRUCTURE:{}".format(n))
```

It then outputs this:

```
    STRUCTURE:(array([array([0.6888437]), array([ 0.51590881, -0.15885684]),
   array([-0.4821665 ,  0.02254944, -0.19013173])], dtype=object), array([list([array([ 0.56759718, -0.39337455])]),
   list([array([-0.04680609,  0.16676408,  0.81622577]), array([ 0.00937371, -0.43632431,  0.51160841])])],
  dtype=object))
```

**Solving the bug**

I can understand from one of the answer to this post that *np.array() tries to create as high a dimensional array as it can, and failing that falls back on object dtype (or for some combinations of inputs raises an error).*

The object dtype gets created in the *build()* function so I tried to remove all *np.array()* functions in that. Actually i removed all of such from the whole script. *And guess what?* **It worked! Thanks a 1000 times to you contributers!**

Btw ***Happy New Year***

Comment: Seems like one of the numpy arrays doesn't contain floats but objects. Figure out which one from your stack trace and fix it. It will also make the code run faster.

Comment: I have already checked the values that are causing the errors, but I can't seem to find what's wrong with them. Thanks for reminding me though. I have added it to the last part of the post now.

Comment: Check `np.array(structure[1])` int he constructor, I think it doesn't do what you think it does, probably because `structure[1]` is already a numpy array of objects.

Comment: Your copy paste test did not create object dtype arrays.

Comment: I solved it! Thanks a 1000 times for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your copy-paste testing:

```
In [55]: np.matmul([1.6888437], [np.array([-0.19013173])])
Out[55]: array([-0.32110277])
```

But this isn't what your code is using.  Instead we have to make arrays that match in dtype.

```
In [59]: x = np.array([1.6888437]); y = np.array([np.array([-0.19013173]),None])[:1]
In [60]: x
Out[60]: array([1.6888437])
In [61]: y
Out[61]: array([array([-0.19013173])], dtype=object)
```

I used the `None` funny business to force it to create an object dtype containing an array, which will `print` as `[array([-0.19013173])]`.

Now I get your error:

```
In [62]: np.matmul(x,y)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-b6212b061655> in <module>()
----> 1 np.matmul(x,y)

TypeError: Object arrays are not currently supported
```

Even if did work as with `dot`

```
In [66]: np.dot(x,y)
Out[66]: array([-0.32110277])
```

the calculations with object dtype arrays are slower.

I won't try to figure out why you have an object dtype array at this point.  But I think you should avoid those in code where speed matters.

If you construct an array from arrays or lists that differ in size, the result is likely to be object dtype with a lower number of dimensions.  `np.array` tries to create as high a dimensional array as it can, and failing that falls back on object dtype (or for some combinations of inputs raises an error).